# How to convert json response into Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I get the JSON response by  `requests.get`

```
req = requests.get(SAMPLE_SCHEDULE_API)
```

and convert it into dictionary

`data = json.loads(req.text)["data"]`

When I tried to convert the string into Python dict,

I got `ValueError: malformed node or string:`

`ast.literal_eval(data)`

I have no idea how to do this task.

## code snippets

```
    def schedules(cls, start_date=None, end_date=None):
        import ast
        req = requests.get(SAMPLE_SCHEDULE_API)
        data = json.loads(req.text)["data"]
        ast.literal_eval(data)
        return pd.DataFrame(json.loads(req.text)["data"])
```

## JSON response

```
{
status: "ok",
version: "v1",
data: "[
{"_id":"2015-01-28","end_date":"2015-01-28","estimated_release":1422453600000,"is_projection":false,"is_statement":true,"material_link":null,"start_date":"2015-01-27"},
{"_id":"2015-03-18","end_date":"2015-03-18","estimated_release":1426687200000,"is_projection":false,"is_statement":false,"material_link":null,"start_date":"2015-03-17"},
{"_id":"2015-04-29","end_date":"2015-04-29","estimated_release":1430316000000,"is_projection":false,"is_statement":false,"material_link":null,"start_date":"2015-04-28"},
{"_id":"2015-06-17","end_date":"2015-06-17","estimated_release":1434549600000,"is_projection":false,"is_statement":false,"material_link":null,"start_date":"2015-06-16"},
{"_id":"2015-07-29","end_date":"2015-07-29","estimated_release":1438178400000,"is_projection":false,"is_statement":false,"material_link":null,"start_date":"2015-07-28"}]"
}
```

## Detail error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fomc.py", line 25, in <module>
    schedules = FOMC.schedules()
  File "fomc.py", line 21, in schedules
    ast.literal_eval(data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/ast.py", line 86, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/ast.py", line 58, in _convert
    return list(map(_convert, node.elts))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/ast.py", line 63, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/ast.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/ast.py", line 85, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x10a19c990>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have encoded the `data` twice (which would strictly not be necessary). You just need to decode the `data` again with `json.loads`:

```
def schedules(cls, start_date=None, end_date=None):
    req = requests.get(SAMPLE_SCHEDULE_API)
    data_json = json.loads(req.text)["data"]
    data = json.loads(data_json)
    return pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

Do note that `ast.literal_eval` is for Python code, whereas `json.loads` is for JSON that closely follows JavaScript code; the differences are for example `true` , `false` and `null` vs `True`, `False` and `None`. The former are the javascript syntax as used in JSON (and thus you would need `json.loads`; the latter is Python code, for which you would use `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: i get "list indices must be integers, not str"

Answer (score 1):

As the response already is json format, you do not need to encode it. Approach like this,

```
req = requests.get(SAMPLE_SCHEDULE_API)
data_str = req.json().get('data')
json_data = json.loads(data_str)
```

`json()` method will return the json-encoded content of a response.

Answer (score 0):

The field "data" is a string, not a list. The content of that string seems to be JSON, too, so you have JSON encapsulated in JSON for some reason. If you can, fix that so that you only encode as JSON once. If that doesn't work, you can retrieve that field and decode it separately.